# SETFILTER - is not equal to (<>) not working NAV 90

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-nav

I have been trying to make use of setfilter but it seems not working

```
FOR i := 1 TO ARRAYLEN(ItemGroupFilter) DO BEGIN
  IF i <> ARRAYLEN(ItemGroupFilter) THEN BEGIN
    IF  ItemGroupFilter[i] <> '' THEN 
      IF ItemGroupString = '' THEN
        ItemGroupString := '<>' + ('%' + FORMAT(i))
      ELSE
        ItemGroupString := ItemGroupString + ('|%' + FORMAT(i))
    ELSE
      ItemGroupString := ItemGroupString;
  END ELSE BEGIN
    IF ItemGroupFilter[i] <> '' THEN
      IF ItemGroupString = '' THEN
        ItemGroupString := '<>' + ('%' + FORMAT(i))
      ELSE
        ItemGroupString := ItemGroupString + ('|%' + FORMAT(i))
    ELSE  
      ItemGroupString := ItemGroupString;
  END;
END;

Item.RESET;
Item.SETFILTER("Item Group",ItemGroupString,ItemGroupFilter[1],ItemGroupFilter[2],ItemGroupFilter[3],ItemGroupFilter[4]);
```

As a result, only the first ItemGroupFilter[1] is doing the job. as from the OR (|) afterwards, it doesnt work

```
Message Values:
    ItemGroupString = '<>%1|%2|%3|%4'
    ItemGroupFilter[1] = '1'
    ItemGroupFilter[2] = '2'
    ItemGroupFilter[3] = '3'
    ItemGroupFilter[4] = '4'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution. SETFILTER for <> should be as follows:

```
SETFILTER('<>%1&<>%2&<>%3&<>%4','1','2','3','4')
```

So my above ItemGroupString Variable consist of

```
ItemGroupString = '<>%1&<>%2&<>%3&<>%4'
```

Happy programming! :)